# Transfer learning or fine-tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code)

```
                                               include_top=False, 
                                               weights='imagenet')

x = base_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = se_model.input,outputs=prediction_layer)



return model
```

Answer (score 1):

When you download the base model, it downloads its architecture along with its weights. It's not possible to train these high-level models from single PC's. That's why we download the pre-trained models from the internet and then fine tune them by re-training them with our own dataset.

```
# Fine-tune from this layer onwards
for layer in model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[fine_tune_at:]:
    layer.trainable=True
```

As you can see above, you are freezing weights of pre-trained models' initial layers as you don't want to mess up with that and only need to change the last output layer based on your I/O.

Comment: So this type of structure is then fine-tuning the DenseNet model?

Comment: Here from this code, you will get a model ready for transfer learning, in full code, after calling this method you will be calling a fit function on the model returned from this function on a dataset of your choice. Hope you get it now.

Comment: @deny we are basically fine-tuning only the last layer. If we have not set the ".trainable = False" we would be fine-tuning the whole DenseNet. The point is that the layers other than the last layer contain very useful information that can't be easily improved upon and hence we try to not mess it up and just update the last layer. You might also come across some examples where you don't even change the last layer instead you add a new layer because the last layer also contains very useful information. a very common example would be BERT.

Comment: Thanks! So that means the code above adjust only the last layer of the network. Do you mean the fully connected layer or which one?